# C++ nested conditional operator order of evaluation

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, operator-keyword, evaluation

For an expression like

```
x = a ? b : c ? d : e;
```

I understand that because the ?: operator has right associativity, the expression is grouped as

```
x = a ? b : (c ? d : e);
```

However, what about order of evaluation? Does associativity mean that the (c ? d : e) branch evaluated first, and then the answer of it passed as an argument to the left ?: operator? Or is a evaluated first, and then depending on that either b is returned or the (c ? d : e) branch is evaluated? Or is it undefined?

Comment: even if I would know the associativity by heart, I would always use parentheses for clarity

Comment: `1 > 2 ? cout << "yes" : cout << "no";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

n3376 5.16/1

> Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It is evaluated and if it
>   is true, the result of the conditional expression is the value of the
>   second expression, otherwise that of the third expression. Only one of
>   the second and third expressions is evaluated. **Every value computation
>   and side effect associated with the first expression is sequenced
>   before every value computation and side effect associated with the
>   second or third expression.**

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly: "a" is converted to bool, and then if it is true "b" is the result, and if it is false then the (c ? d : e) branch is evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

For the conditional operator:

- the first operand is evaluated first;
- either the second or the third (but not both) is evaluated depending on the value of the first.